# Why is j < i in this solution for rotating a matrix 90 degrees?

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix

I'm reading through this Javascript solution for rotating an nxn matrix clockwise 90 degrees, but I'm having a hard time understanding why in the second for loop (line 4) j is set to be less than i. Where is this logic coming from? And why does setting j less than matrix[i].length there not work?

```js
let matrix = [
  [1, 2],
  [3, 4]
];

var rotate = function(matrix) {
  matrix = matrix.reverse();
  for (var i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      var temp = matrix[i][j];
      matrix[i][j] = matrix[j][i];
      matrix[j][i] = temp;
    }
  }
};
rotate(matrix);
console.log(matrix);
```

Comment: If the inner loop goes all the way to the end of the row, you'll swap every element twice, which will not produce the correct result.

Comment: See what happens if you change that to `j < matrix[i].length`. It ends up reversing the rows.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks!